# grab nth line in perl where n can be four integers

Tags: perl

I would like to take four lines from a file using Perl. I have four integer variables; for instance:

```
a= 5;
b = 45;
c=30;
d=8;
```

Is it possible to grab and store as four strings the line numbers from a file that correspond to these values (i.e. line 5, line 45, line 30, line 8)? I have been playing around with

```
-ne 'print if($.==5)';
```

But is there a more eloquent way? This just seems to check for what line I am currently on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it as a one-liner, using a hash makes it pretty easy:

```
perl -ne '%lines = map { $_ => 1 } 23, 45, 78, 3; print if exists $lines{$.}' test.txt
```

This creates a hash that looks like `( 23 => 1, 45 => 1, 78 => 1, 3 => 1 )` and then uses `exists` to check if the current line number is a key in the hash.

Comment: And if you need to keep them you could use the hash for that, too; initialize it with `undef` values or a sentinel value which cannot occur in your data.

Comment: The word `exists` could be dropped.

Comment: It sure could; I guess I'm just in the habit of being explicit with hash key tests.

Comment: sidenote, `%lines =..` is inside loop

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with a small file and have the memory to slurp the contents into the script, you could slurp the file into an array and then access the lines as array elements:

```
# define the lines you want to capture
$a=5;
$b=45;
$c=30;
$d=8;

# slurp the file into an array
@file = <>;

# push the contents of the array back by one
# so that the line numbers are what you expect
# (otherwise you would have to add 1 to get the
# line you are looking for)
unshift (@file, "");

# access the desired lines directly as array elements
print $file[$a];
print $file[$b];
print $file[$c];
print $file[$d];
```

If you're looking for command line one-liners, you could also try awk or sed:

```
awk 'NR==5' file.txt
sed -n '5p' file.txt
```

Comment: Slurping the whole file may be inefficient if it's big.

Answer (score 2):

one liner

```
 perl -ne 'print if ( $. =~ /^45$|^30$|^8$|^5$/  )' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely the job that [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) is good for.

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'myfile.txt';

print $file[$_-1], "\n" for qw/ 5 45 30 8 /;
```